# Access to property from method - Java

Tags: java, variables, methods

I got maybe a dumb question, i want to access to a local property from method for example:

```
public class Example {
    private int myprop;
    public int getMyprop() {
        return myprop;
    }

    public void setMyprop(int myprop) {
        this.myprop= myprop;
    }

    public void useProperty(){
    // i want to use here the variable: 'myprop' how i can accomplish this?
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Fix you `get` method.

Comment: You can use this variable directly or via a getter (after you fix it).

Comment: Sorry, if i fix that i just access the variable with my get method?

Comment: `this.myprop` doesn't work?

Comment: You don't need to use the get method from within the class. You can use myprop directly.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, i used this.myprop . Thanks

Comment: You don't need this.myprop. it's just myprop.

Comment: @PaulBoddington You don't *need* to, but it's a good programming style to always qualify field access with `this.`.

Comment: Is it? I'm not sure I agree with that but you got an upvote from me for referencing Douglas Adams.

Answer (score 1):

Same way you did in `getMyprop()`: By name.

```
public void useProperty(){
    if (myprop == 42) {
        System.out.println("It's the Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. You can do like your getter one or you can use your getter also:

//use directly "myprop"

```
 public void useProperty(){
    // access directly "myprop" here
    System.out.println("Access directly myprop: " + this.myprop);

   }
```

//Or use getter

```
 public void useProperty(){
    // access by using getter
    System.out.println("Access myprop via getter: " + this.getMyprop());
   }
```

Hope this help